# Return a string by using if...else in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

so here I am trying to convert the string `' ABcsad f!,'` into
string `'abcsadf'`,
so basically I am trying to replace the space and non-alpha into ''
but my code not working at all...

```
s = ' ABcsad f!,'

def norm(s):
    b=''
    i=0
    for i in range(0,len(s)+1):
        if (s[i].isalpha() is False) or (s[i].isspace() is False) :
            return b+=''
        else:
            return b+=s[i]
        i = i+1   

print(norm(s))
```

anyone can tell me which part I goes wrong?

Comment: Does b+="" even work in python?Also returning every time? And returning an expression?

Comment: @gst1502 Yes, but unlike some other languages it isn't an expression that has a value, so you can't return it.

Comment: Aren't you returning too early, you are supposed to return `b` no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, your code has errors because you are trying to return `b` at an invalid position.

Your code

```
return b+=''
```

in python does not work as expected in languages like Java. You have to return `b` explicitly.

Though its not the best way, just tried to use the same code what you wrote , but in a correct way (not pythonian way ;-))

```
s = ' ABcsad f!,'

def norm(s):
    b=''
    i=0
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        if not s[i].isalpha() or s[i].isspace():
            b += ''
        else:
            b += s[i]
        i = i+1
    return b

print(norm(s))
```

There are more ways like use of regex , replace operations to do this operation more efficiently in python. Hope you get the mistake.

Comment: Why even do `b += ''`? If you want a code line that does nothing use `pass`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
s = ' ABcsad f!,'
def norm(s):
    return ''.join(i for i in s.lower() if i.isalpha())
print(norm(s))
```

**Output** :

```
'abcsadf'
```

Comment: `''.join(i for i in s if i.isalpha()).lower()` is more efficient (fewer function calls).

Answer (score 4):

Here is where you went wrong

1. You put the return inside the for loop. Return exits the entire `norm` function rather than allowing the for loop to finish. It needed to be moved outside.
2. `len(s) + 1` causes an out of range error. It should just be `len(s)`
3. As you want to remove spaces, `s[i].isspace()` should be checked for being true.
4. If you want everything lowercase, you need to make `s[i]` to `s[i].lower()`
5. You can use `b += ...` but you cannot use it in its own return statement. It is irrelevant anyway as you should not be using return there.

```
def norm(s):
    b=''
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        if (s[i].isalpha() is False) or (s[i].isspace() is True):
            b += ""
        else:
            b += s[i].lower()
        i = i+1
    return b

s = ' ABcsad f!,'
print(norm(s))
```

Answer (score 2):

May be with regex:

```
import re

mystring = ' ABcsad f!,'
print (re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', mystring)).lower()
```

*Output:*

```
abcsadf
```

Answer (score 0):

You returned `b` after the first iteration. No matter what the first character is, you returned `b` which did not let the loop go through your string. So, you need to keep `return b` out of loop. And also there is no need to `return b+=s[i]`. Just `return b+s[i]` would have been okay. In fact, you can't assign a value in return statement. However, the code can be cut short like the following:

```py
s = ' ABcsad f!,'

def norm(s):
    b=''
    i=0
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        if s[i].isalpha():
            b+=s[i]
    return b.lower()

print(norm(s))
```